# Revoking a privilege from a user given the privilege by another user

Tags: sql, database

Suppose that I grant *User1* the SELECT privilege on *Table* with GRANT OPTION. Then suppose that *User1* grants *User2* the same privilege. Under a SQL-like model, is it possible for me (the DBA) to revoke *User2*'s privilege without affecting *User1*'s privilege?

Comment: Sure you can revoke it, but then *User1* can just grant it again. If you don't want that to happen, you cannot use `WITH GRANT OPTION`.

Comment: It might help if you provide a bit of context on why you need this particular arrangement.

Comment: @Alejandro To make sure, you could simply do it with the following command, right?   `REVOKE SELECT ON Table FROM User2`